# How do I get ALL posts in a category with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

This works pretty good except it is limited to 10 posts since my blog is set to show 10 posts maximum.

```
   $featured_query = new WP_Query('cat=3');

        while( $featured_query->have_posts() ){
            $featured_query->the_post();
            $postcount++;
            ...
```

How can I override that setting and get ALL posts in that category regardless of the maximum posts setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `showposts=-1`. This will override the defaults posts setting. Per this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: awesome, thanks.  i was actually reading that page but I missed that little point.

Answer (score 1):

This is best way to do the list of a particular category..

```
>  $catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("NameOfTheCategory"));

> foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
>        <div>
>              <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
>              <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
>        </div> <?php  endforeach;?>
```

Thanks
MrPhpGuru

Answer (score 0):

Does query_posts('cat=3') do what you want?

Comment: Fair enough, the -1 parameter is needed--I didn't know that one either